# Formula to extract specific information from a column of cells

Tags: excel

So I have a column with information like this:

```
XC-163 0827m Timber problems
0600m failed picture cv-76
ligts out 0987m p3
... etc
```

What I need is to create a column only with the measurement information in it which goes before the `m`, in this case:

```
0827
0600
0987
```

Any ideas of which functions I can use?

Comment: Always 4 digits then *m*? Always one *0000m* per string?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice little user defined function. It belongs in a standard public module (alt+F11, Insert, Module).

```
Option Explicit

Function fourEm(str As String)
    Static rgx As Object

    If rgx Is nothing Then _
        Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With rgx
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{4}(?=m)"
        If .test(str) Then
            fourEm = .Execute(str)(0)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regex is eminently sensible but *for your sample data* the following works too:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("m ",A1)-4,4)
```